# Spring MVC - <form:errors> empty, BindingResult contains errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, spring-annotations

I am experiencing some issues with @Valid and BindingResult not pushing errors to the returned jsp page. The BindingResult in the method, detects binding errors correctly but the only way I can currently display errors is by manually adding result.getAllErrors() to the page. None of the following  elements work:

```
<form:form name="updateForm" commandName="dataModel" method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pages/data">

    <form:errors path="*" />
    <form:errors />


    <c:forEach items="${dataModel.rows}" var="data" varStatus="currRow">
        <c:out value="${data.code}" />
        <form:errors path="dataRows[${currRow.index}].tolPercentage" />
        <form:input path="dataRows[${currRow.index}].tolPercentage" />
    </c:forEach>

</form:form>
```

Controller class method:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("dataModel")
public class DataControllerController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(
            @ModelAttribute("dataModel") @Valid DataModel dataModel ,
            BindingResult result
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("DataFormPage");

        if ( result.hasErrors() ) {
            model.addAllObjects(result.getModel());
        } else {
            ...
        }

        return model;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("dataModel")
    public DataModel getDataModel() {
        return new DataModel();
    }

}
```

Form field:

```
@Min(0)
@Max(1)
@Digits(fraction=2, integer = 1)
@Column(name="TOL_PERCENTAGE", precision = 1, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal tolPercentage;
```

I have looked through the majority of existing questions related to BindingResult and errors but none have worked.

Comment: Can you add a bit more page code? Is the `form:errors` inside your `form:form` tag for example?

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven, I have added the rest of my form now.

Comment: Try the following in your errors if: `ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(NAMEPAGE);  modelAndView.addObject("dataModel", dataModel); return modelAndView;`

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven, tried the following and I still have no errors shown on my page...

Comment: Please provide source of the DataModel class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this problem by switching on the Optimistic Serialization flag in the Weblogic 12c Console. Hope this will help others.